# How to format inline razor variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, razor

Razor does a great job of knowing what you want to do when it's simple.  I just want to format a variable from a query and am a bit confused.  Everything works great, except the one line with the if string isnull statement in it.   The compiler fails on the line with the { &nbsp } saying it expects a semicolon ;.   Here's the code:

```
@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){ 
<tr> 
       <td>@row.ACCT &nbsp &nbsp</td> 
       <td>@row.QuoteStart &nbsp &nbsp</td> 
       <td>@row.VIN &nbsp &nbsp </td>
       <td>@{ if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.AmountFinanced) == true) 
                 { &nbsp } else 
                 {String.Format("{0:0,0.00}",row.AmountFinanced) &nbsp &nbsp }
            } </td>
       <td>@row.Step &nbsp &nbsp </td>


</tr> 
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap your `&nbsp;`s in a `<text></text>` block. This forces the parser to escape back into html because when you're in a `{}` block the parser will assume that the `&nbsp;` is supposed to be code.

```
@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){ 
<tr> 
       <td>@row.ACCT &nbsp &nbsp;</td> 
       <td>@row.QuoteStart &nbsp; &nbsp;</td> 
       <td>@row.VIN &nbsp; &nbsp; </td>
       <td>@{ if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.AmountFinanced) == true) 
                 { <text>&nbsp;</text> } else 
                 { @String.Format("{0:0,0.00}",row.AmountFinanced) <text>&nbsp; &nbsp;</text> }
            } </td>
       <td>@row.Step &nbsp; &nbsp; </td>
</tr> 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the correction in code. I think you need a @ before the String.Format. Here's the final code i used (I had to convert a string back to a number to be able to add the thousands indicator): { @String.Format("{0:0,0.00}",Convert.ToDouble(row.AmountFinanced)) <text> &nbsp &nbsp </text> }}
If you edit your answer, I'll mark it as accepted.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're right about the @ because you're going to output it to the screen. I was more concerned about the `&nbsp;` Updated. Thanks :)